# How to recursively copy file an folder in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following script, which take a source folder and copy using FileStream files to another folder.

I need to change it in a way to recursively get any sub-folders and copy their files too.

How to modifythe method?

```
- source folder
  - file
  - file
  - folder
     - file
     - file
     - folder
       - file
  - folder
     - file
     - file
     - folder
       - file





 public static void SynchFolders()
    {
        DirectoryInfo StartDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(SourceUNC);
        DirectoryInfo EndDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(TargetUNC);

        foreach (FileInfo file in StartDirectory.EnumerateFiles())
        {
            using (FileStream SourceStream = file.OpenRead())
            {
                string dirPath = StartDirectory.FullName;
                string outputPath = dirPath.Replace(StartDirectory.FullName, EndDirectory.FullName);
                using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(outputPath + "\\" + file.Name))
                {
                    SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is to expand your function slightly such that after copying all files found in a particular directory, it will then search for subfolders within the current folder and recurse into that folder so that the same procedure is carried out on each subfolder.

An example function, based on your original code :

```
 public static void SynchFolders(string SourceUNC, string TargetUNC)
    {
        DirectoryInfo StartDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(SourceUNC);
        DirectoryInfo EndDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(TargetUNC);

        // Copy Files
        foreach (FileInfo file in StartDirectory.EnumerateFiles())
        {
            using (FileStream SourceStream = file.OpenRead())
            {
                string dirPath = StartDirectory.FullName;
                string outputPath = dirPath.Replace(StartDirectory.FullName, EndDirectory.FullName);
                using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(outputPath + "\\" + file.Name))
                {
                    SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
                }
            }
        }

        // Copy subfolders
        var folders = StartDirectory.EnumerateDirectories();
        foreach (var folder in folders)
        {
            // Create subfolder target path by concatenating folder name to original target UNC
            string target = Path.Combine(TargetUNC, folder.Name);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target);

            // Recurse into the subfolder
            SynchFolders(folder.FullName, target);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: just a quick one, how would you set the buffer-size for FileStream  in your example? thanks

Comment: @GibboK That is easy to do inside the constructor of the destination stream

using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(outputPath + "\\" + file.Name, 8*1024))

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Copy Directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914(v=vs.110).aspx) is an article from MSDN showing how to do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

#### Read this MSDN Tutorial (exacly what you need): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762914(v=vs.110).aspx

**Note:** if you'd like to use `SourceStream.CopyToAsync` instead of `file.CopyTo`, just replace it with your original snippet